# List of CSS Properties That Can Be Transitioned

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm looking at CSS transitions, in particular which CSS properties can be transitioed and their respective browser support. Struggling to find anything comprehensive on google.

I believe that not all CSS properties are transitional. For example, `background:` isn't, but `background-color:` and `background-image:` are.

Would this mean that CSS transitions only work on long-hand syntax? Or perhaps this example is just an exception.

Does anyone have a comprehensive list of properties that can be transitioned?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties

Comment: Do you mean compatibility with elements and attributes accross version s of browsers or animations

Comment: I mean a list of properties that the can be used by the "transition:" property. That w3.org list isn't comprehensive at all. Border-radius isn't on it for example. See here http://jsfiddle.net/BpgQK/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Answer (score 5):

> Would this mean that CSS transitions only work on long-hand syntax? Or perhaps this example is just an exception.

It works on shorthand properties, but only for specific longhand components that are animatable. This is mentioned in the [CSS Transitions spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-property-property).

If you specify `transition-property: background`, for example, it will work, but only `background-color`, `background-position` and `background-size`, as well as gradient values in `background-image`, will be animated, and they will all animate according to the delay, timing function and duration specified for the `background` transition.

I suspect asking for links to lists of properties might be off-topic here, but for what it's worth, [MDN contains a list of animatable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

For most properties, whether or not — and how — they're animatable is also described in their respective propdefs (specifications). For example, the definition of `border-radius` can be in the [Backgrounds and Borders module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius):

> *Animatable:* as two values of [length, percentage, or calc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animtype-lpcalc)

Like `background-image`, `border-radius` is a shorthand property, made up of four components (one for each corner). You can transition all four corners the exact same way by simply specifying `transition-property: border-radius`, and exactly one delay, timing function and duration.

Comment: I'm unsure how to contribute appropriately to this well written answer. The link to CSS Transitions in the 3rd paragraph now redirects and the anchor is no longer valid.  MDN has a page "Animatable CSS properties", https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties.

Comment: @Richard Michael: Looks like they moved that section to a separate document called Web Animations, but it's a massive document so I'll use the MDN link you've provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is [animatable-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/animatable-properties) package on npm based on the [MDN list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

`animatable.propertiesCSS` is an array containing all the animatable properties in CSS format.

You can also get a list of them sorted by usage popularity based on [Chrome's anonymous usage statistics](https://chromestatus.com/metrics/css/animated).

```js
console.log('First 10 properties by usage statistics:', animatable.popular())
console.log('All properties sorted alphabetically:', animatable.propertiesCSS)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/animatable-properties"></script>
```

The package also provides syntax for each property and ability to validate that syntax.